# Problem xcode no work xcode/MAMP/PhpStorm/Mac

Tags: php, macos, phpstorm, mamp, xdebug

I have been through the forums without success. I'm trying to use xcode with PhpStorm on my pimp. I use MAMP/PHP 7.1.19.

When I do a `phpinfo()` I have nothing about Xdebug.

I have two php.ini files:

```
-/Applications/MAMP/conf/php7.3.0/php.ini

-/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.1/conf/php.ini
```

I modified both files with:

```
-zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so"
```

I have of course check if the file `xdebug.so` exists.

Comment: what does this have to do with xcode ?

Comment: ha damn it, I was wrong, sorry.

Comment: did you restart apache after you modified the ini files ?   Are you certain that it is the MAMP apache answering. How do you do `phpinfos()` ... if it is at the cli , check the version to make certain you are not running a version other than mamp's php.

Comment: Try to remove the minus in `-zend_extension`, or is it just a typo in the query?

Comment: Hello, Yes I restarted r apache after modifying the.ini files. how can I be sure that it is the apache mamp that answers? I do phpinfo() from my website directly in the code. the' -''. (less) is not in the php.ini file I added it in the description.

Answer (score 0):

If the file xdebug.so exists then you have to enable it in the `php.ini`. At the end of the file you have uncommented the `zend_extension`but you have to enable it. Add this:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/tmp/xdebug/"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_log="/usr/local/var/log/httpd/xdebug.log"
xdebug.default_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=1000
```

For someone else who doesn't have the `xdebug.so` file, you have to install the Xdebug extension with PECL. Open the terminal and paste:
`cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.1/bin` and then install xdebug `./pecl install xdebug`